# Is Cloud Storage uploading files in a queue?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

We're developing a software that uploads files to cloud storage every 5 minutes. If the internet connection is lost, then we save the files locally and upload all of them once the connection is resumed. Since StorageReference.putFile() is an asynchronous method, as we loop through the different files and call the method, are those files uploaded in a queue, meaning other files have to wait while this file is uploading, or those files will be uploaded in different threads, meaning there is no guarantee which one will be uploaded first? Those files will be in the same bucket, and our goal is to upload the files chronologically. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase SDKs don't make any guarantees about the order of upload.  They also upload files concurrently, but limit the number of concurrent uploads.  If you require more specific requirements about the order of upload, you should implement your own queuing system.

If you want to see exactly what the SDKs are doing, they are open source and can be found with a simple web search.